# How to extract multiple objects from string using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want a solution to extract object & push into an array. but can not able to extract object because

```
const data = [ "userData": ["{ name: 'Test 1', age: '25'}, { name: 'Test 2', age: '26'}, { name: 'Test 3', age: '27'},"] ]
```

Tried code,

```
const test = data[0]['userData'];
const converted = JSON.parse(test);
```

Above code doesn't work.

**Expected Output:**

```
[
  {
    name: 'Test 1',
    age: '25'
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 2',
    age: '26'
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 3',
    age: '27'
  },
]
```

Comment: That happens because `JSON.parse` only accepts strings, and you are passing an array of strings. You must iterate through the array of strings and parse each element individually, and then push each result to an array.

Comment: Can you give me an example ?

Comment: Sure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript there is plenty of examples there. As a tip, the `map` answer should do the trick for you. I'm not going to add the exact code so you try to understand what is happening and how to overcome it, as an excercise, as it seems that you are learning and that's important ;-)

Comment: data format seems to be wrong. gives an error when pasted in console Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Comment: I know data format is wrong, but i can not change the format because data comes from the external resource.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way the json is formed.
Try this:

```js
const data = [ '{"userData": [{ "name": "Test 1", "age": 25}, { "name": "Test 2", "age": 26}, { "name": "Test 3", "age": 27}]}']
console.log(JSON.parse(data[0]))
```

Comment: I know data format is wrong, but i can not change the format because data comes from the external resource.

Comment: can u share example raw request from the external resource? @Manoj Ghediya

Comment: I have shared sample data in question description,

const data = [ "userData": ["{ name: 'Test 1', age: '25'}, { name: 'Test 2', age: '26'}, { name: 'Test 3', age: '27'},"] ]

Comment: It's impossible to parse because if u cant change the format, the ':' results in error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Comment: I know, but i need to fix this as soon as possible